# Center number with 1 and 2 digit

Tags: html, css, position

I have a shape which is a heart and I have a number inside. The problem is that I can have a number with 1 digit and a number with 2 digit and I am not able to center them into the heart.

https://jsfiddle.net/b7ggddqy/

```css
.description{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
}
.heart{
    z-index:-500;
    position: absolute;
    top:70%;
    right:20%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #BF4139;
}
.heart:before,
.heart:after{
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    content: '';
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #BF4139;
}
.heart:before{
    bottom: 0px;
    left: -15px;
}
.heart:after{
    top: -15px;
    right: 0px;
}
.heart p{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 800;
    left:10px;
    top:-15px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="description">
 <div class="heart">
         <p>11</p>
 </div>
</div>     
<div class="description">
 <div class="heart">
         <p>3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give a width to the paragraph and `text-align:center`

```
.heart p {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 800;
    left:3px;
    top:0px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:white;
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/b7ggddqy/3/

Answer (score 2):

Set `p` width to 100% and `text-align:center`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.heart p{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width:20px;
    margin-left:-13px;
    }
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7ggddqy/2/)**

Comment: Yes thank you, and do you know why when I change left to 0, the text go up ?